# How to tweet multiple lines with Tweepy?

Tags: python, string, twitter, tweepy

How can I tweet this...

```
List of fruits:
1. Apple
2. Banana
3. Orange
```

Instead of this?

```
List of fruits: 1. Apple 2. Banana 3. Orange
```

My code so far:

```
import tweepy

# Authenticate connection
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(token_key, token_secret)

# Start API
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Update status
api.update_status('List of fruits: \n1. Apple \n2. Banana \n3. Orange')
```

As you can see, using '\n' didn't work. Tweepy just ignored it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call an external API, it need not be written in Python on the server end. So maybe the '\n' is simply being caught as an exception. Or probably, the encoding is changed to ignore the escape characters.

What you can do is:

```
with open('temp.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write('List of fruits: \n1. Apple \n2. Banana \n3. Orange')

import tweepy

# Authenticate connection
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(token_key, token_secret)

# Start API
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Update status
with open('temp.txt','r') as f:
   api.update_status(f.read())
```

Comment: Glad I could help