# How to add multiple lines of text in tweepy in one tweet

Tags: tweepy

I'm trying to make a twitter bot that post once daily. I want it to say "Day 1" as well as the hashtag under it.
Such as "Day 1
Ex3"
How could I make this happen?

```
#Options For Hashtag
hashtag = {
    "0": 'Ex1', 
    "1": 'Ex2', 
    "2": 'Ex3', 
    "3": 'Ex4', 
    "4": 'Ex5'
}

day = 0
day_add = day = day + 1
day_num = "Day ", day_add


client.create_tweet(text = random.choice(list(hashtag.values())))
```

I've tried to do things such as
client.create_tweet(text = random.choice(list(hashtag.values(), (day_num))))
and
client.create_tweet(text = day_num, random.choice(list(hashtag.values())))
Neither work
And yes, before this gets removed or downvoted, I have looked at [How to tweet multiple lines with Tweepy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999658/how-to-tweet-multiple-lines-with-tweepy)
and some others, none seem to answer my question though

Answer (score 0):

you can do this,

```
#Options For Hashtag
hashtag = {
    "0": 'Ex1', 
    "1": 'Ex2', 
    "2": 'Ex3', 
    "3": 'Ex4', 
    "4": 'Ex5'
}

day = 0
day_add = day = day + 1

day_num = "Day ", day_add

random_hashtag = random.choice(list(hashtag.values()))

tweet_text = day_num + "\n" + random_hashtag 

client.create_tweet(text = tweet_text )
```

note: that \n means new line so hashtag is in next line then the day num.